I am facing error when tring to download ftp link using url
this the error I am facing trying URL 'ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/subset/202404050438gr5H_n_1msibTNA'
Error in download.file(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), paste(getwd(),  :
cannot open URL 'ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/subset/202404050438gr5H_n_1msibTNA'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), paste(getwd(),  :
cannot open URL 'ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/subset/202404050438gr5H_n_1msibTNA': FTP status was '550 Requested action not taken; file unavailable'
I used this code
library(RCurl)
library(data.table)
# Set the location where data should be saved
setwd("D:/hydrology_climate/access0")
# Change to the FTP url for the subset request. This is provided in the
# DCP notification email (sent from no-reply@gdo4.llnl.gov).
options(download.file.method="libcurl", url.method="libcurl")
url = "ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/subset/202404050438gr5H_n_1msibT"
filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r\n")
filenames = unlist(filenames)
tmp = data.table(filenames)
zips = tmp[filenames %like% 'zip']
txts = tmp[filenames %like% 'txt']

nzips = as.numeric(nrow(zips))
for (i in 1:nzips) {
filename = zips[i]
download.file(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), paste(getwd(), "/", filename,sep = ""))
}
 ntxts = as.numeric(nrow(txts))
for (i in 1:ntxts) {
filename = txts[i]
download.file(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), paste(getwd(), "/", filename,sep = ""))
}


According to the error "550 Requested action not taken; file unavailable" the file doesn't exist (or at least, not accessible to you).

The Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect, please verify all recommended tags for applicability to your problem. In this case, [tag:data.table] is tangential to the issue, it is only here because you used it once to frame-up some file names.

Bottom line, this problem is 100% that the link you have is stale, requires auth (seems unlikely here), has a typo, or the server has temporarily "lost" the file. There is no programming that can fix it from your end. Go back to where you retrieved this URL and find out if there are alternative ways to get to your data.

https://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/downscaled_cmip_projections/dcpInterface.html#Projections:%20Subset%20Request suggests to me that yesterday (Apr 5, 2024) you (or somebody near your) requested a subset of data. Soon after that, an email was sent to the requester. I suggest you go back to that email for two reasons: (1) confirm the URL is exactly as provided in the email; and (2) read the fine print to see if there are restrictions on how long they'll keep the file or other constraints for retrieving the file. If it's clear and should be there, my other guess is that they have a "contact us".
